# ProcessBuilder function used to invoke C# .exe file from Java causing the program to hang

Tags: java, c#, javafx

I am using Java code to invoke a console application written in C# using Visual Studio. ProcessBuilder function is being used. The output produced by the c# code is getting printed on to the IntelliJ console. But then the program hangs. This is a GUI program. Name and password are taken from the interface. The code snippet shown below belongs to function1() which is invoked when a button is clicked after entering the username and password

This is the code that I have written:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\file\\bin\\Debug\\file.exe",name,password).start();
InputStream processInputStream = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(processInputStream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    System.out.println(line);

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:javafx]? Your codes snippet doesn't seem to use this GUI API...

Comment: Is this in fact a GUI program, and are you forgetting to read from the outside process using a background thread? If you don't do this, you risk blocking the GUI's event thread, which would effectively freeze the entire program.

Comment: This is a GUI based program. Username and password are taken  from the interface

Comment: Then the duplicate is valid